# Trigger deployment of Docker container on demand

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

I have a web application that helps my client launch an API with a button "Launch my API".

Under the hood, I have a Docker image that is ran on two Google Cloud Run services (one for debug environment and one for production).

My challenge is the following: How can I trigger the deployment of new Docker containers on-demand ?

Naively, I would like that this button call an API that trigger the launch of these services based on my Docker image (that is already in Google Cloud or available to download at a certain URL).

Ultimately, I'll need to use Kubernetes to manage all of my container's clients. Maybe I should look into that for triggering new container deployments ?

I tried to glue together (I'm very new to the cloud) a Google Cloud function that trigger a new service on Google Cloud Run based on my docker image but with no success.

Comment: The mechanism for doing this on Kubernetes will be very different (and somewhat safer) than pure Docker and you should make that technology choice first.  But in general, launching a container per end user tends to not scale well (what happens if a user presses that button multiple times?) and I might reconsider this design.

Comment: What do you mean by trigger the deployment of a new container on demand ? Do you want to deploy a new version of the container after changes are made to the code ?

In Cloud Run you have a concept of revisions, each service has 1 or many revisions, each revision uses 1 image. You can simply build and push a new container image to GCR with a new tag and create a new revision based on this new container

Comment: I am also on the same page, where we need an option to trigger the containers on demand. Let me know if you have got any solution around the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) on one of your servers and [authorize it](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing)
via service account to perform certain actions. After that, you should be able to trigger a script via HTTP call, cloud fn or what have you, i.e.

```
gcloud run deploy client-specific-api-com \
--image=us-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/myimage:tag \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--port=8080 \
--service-account=my-serive-account@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
--min-instances=1 \
--max-instances=10 \
--no-cpu-throttling \
--cpu-boost \
--region=us-central1 \
--project=myproject
```